# Regex to match non integers?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Trying to create a regex that ignores a proper integer (`1`, `5`, `999`, etc.) and forward slashes (`/`), but finds a match in everything else. For example, it would find a match the following:

- `test`
- `test1`
- `test-1`

but ignores

- `1`
- `55`
- `7`

This is for a mod rewrite.

Comment: Should it allow floating point numbers? E.g `1.337`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[^-0-9\/]+` should do the trick, I think. It'll match any string that contains a non-digit.

Edited to add minus sign which would also be allowed in an integer, and then to include the forward slashes mentioned in the question.

Comment: will it also matched mixed strings?  I want to be able to match strings they may have numbers that mixed in but ignore strings that are just numbers.

Comment: Yes, because mixed strings contain non-digits.

Comment: thanks.  I think that did it.  I did edit it though to ignore forward slashes, though: [^-0-9/]+

Comment: The regex itself won't match mixed strings, but mod_rewrite will with it because mod_rewrite matches any string containing the regex you give it.

Comment: @shelman: Why would it not match mixed strings? Mixed strings contain non-digits, and that regex matches one or more non-digits (and non minus signs/forward slashes).

Comment: Won't it only match the parts of the string that are non-digits, instead of the whole string?  I might be wrong here.

Comment: That's the _parts_ that it would match, but I took the important part to be that it would _find_ a match. I do understand your point, though.

Comment: @DimitryK, depending on the language (not all regex's support `\d` or `\D`), you could do `[^-\d\/]+`.

Comment: This regex will not match any part of `1-1` or `1-`, which clearly are not proper integers and thus should be matched.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but I noticed that the currently accepted answer (`[^-0-9\/]`) will not match any part of a number string that has a dash/minus (`-`) in the middle or at the end or purely consists of dashes.

So the regex will **not** find a match in strings like `12-34`, `1234-`, `--12`, `-`, or `-----`, even though these are clearly not valid integer numbers and should thus be caught.

To include these in the regex, you can use something like this:

```
[^-0-9]+|[0-9]+(?=-)|^-$|-{2,}
```

This will match

- *either* any part of a string that contains a non-digit, non-minus character (as does the regex from the currently accepted answer)
- *or* any number that is followed by a minus sign `-` (using a positive lookahead, taking care of the numbers with dashes anywhere but the beginning)
- *or* any string that consists of one single dash
- *or* any part of a string with two or more consecutive dashes

This will thus find a match in any string that is not a positive or negative integer, see also https://regex101.com/r/8zJwCy/1

---

To also include (or rather exclude) slashes, as the OP requested, they can be added to the first character group.

```
[^-0-9\/]+|[0-9]+(?=-)|^-$|-{2,}
```

Note that this will also not match pure series of slashes (`/`, `//`, `///`,...) and multiple slashes between integers (`1//2`, `1//-2`, `//1`, `2//`) which may or may not be desired (the currently accepted answer behaves identically), see https://regex101.com/r/8zJwCy/3

To also catch these, add another two optional groups that match series of slashes, analogous to the last two ones that take care of the dashes. Or, if you want a single individual slash (`/`) to be valid, just add one group analogous to the last one, see https://regex101.com/r/8zJwCy/4

```
[^-0-9\/]+|[0-9]+(?=-)|^-$|-{2,}|\/{2,}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would match line by line - is that what you need?
    `^[0-9\/]*$`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job!

```
^[0-9\/]+$
```