# Is there a way to customize error messages shown by PyInputPlus?

Tags: python

I've recently learned about PyInputPlus and how to use it.
It is really awesome, but I am wondering is there a way to customize error messages that PyInputPlus shows when user enters invalid values.
For example, in the code below

```
import pyinputplus as pyip
response=pyip.inputInt('please, enter a number: ')
```

if a user enters letter 's',  PyInputPlus shows -

> 's' is not an integer

I would like to cutomize that message, to show it in a different (non-english) language.
I tried to find the solution in the official documentation at [PyInputPlus](https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but found nothing except using **inputCustom** which I am not interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on doing this with PyInputPlus, you can get the desired behavior using the parameter `blockRegexes`, which permits setting a custom error message (in the documentation, this is apparently wrongly documented for the non-existing parameter `blocklistRegexes` in [PyInputPlus parameters](https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyinputplus.parameters)):

> `blocklistRegexes` (Sequence, None): A sequence of regex str or `(regex_str, error_msg_str)` tuples that, if matched, will explicitly fail validation.

Since it is simpler to write a regex that matches only integers than one that matches everything except them, I first used `blockRegexes` to forbid everything using the regex `.*` and then `allowRegexes` to add exceptions for integers using the regex `^-?\d+$'` (only positive and negative integers, see https://regex101.com/r/1ymJzE/1).

The following example accepts negative or positive integers and prints a custom Spanish error message otherwise:

```
import pyinputplus as pyip

response = pyip.inputInt('please, enter a number: ',
             allowRegexes=[r'^-?\d+$'],
             blockRegexes=[(r'.*','¡Esto no es un número entero!')]
           )
```

Execution:

```
please, enter a number: a
¡Esto no es un número entero!
please, enter a number: 1-2
¡Esto no es un número entero!
please, enter a number: 3.2
¡Esto no es un número entero!
please, enter a number: 5,4
¡Esto no es un número entero!
please, enter a number: -12
```

You could also achieve the same with only `blockRegexes` by providing a regex that accepts everything but integers. This regex is a bit more complex if negative numbers should be allowed. See [this answer to a respective question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66522282/14015737) for a detailed explanation of the regex.

This code achieves the same result as the one above:

```
import pyinputplus as pyip

response = pyip.inputInt('please, enter a number: ',
             blockRegexes=[(r'[^-0-9]+|[0-9]+(?=-)|^-$|-{2,}','¡Esto no es un número entero!')]
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to handle it as an exception. Put the logic in a 'try' block and what you want to show as error in the exception block.

```
try:
    #code logic
except SyntaxError: #for example
    print("You encountered a syntax error. ")
```

You can write the name of the error you're getting where I've written "SyntaxError".

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I changed **"SyntaxError"** with **"pyip.ValidationException"** but it is still returning the default message.

Answer (score 0):

To start, I would highly discourage using 3rd-party libraries whenever possible, because they will add faults you do not understand to your code. Many are extraordinarily useful, are well-supported, and/or have some feature it would take you an age to reproduce.

However, you can use `int(input())` for this case, so do so!
(it will behave much more the way you expect)

Digging in the code, the [validation actually calls *another* 3rd-party library](https://github.com/asweigart/pyinputplus/blob/89bb95a767fda9366d63b661d7d39e077d5118e4/src/pyinputplus/__init__.py#L473) by the same author

This looks like it goes to the code [path here where the real Exception is](https://github.com/asweigart/pysimplevalidate/blob/98c17951be29689b5f5508c8ab9721dd44c55a9f/src/pysimplevalidate/__init__.py#L527) and then goes [here to be caught](https://github.com/asweigart/pyinputplus/blob/89bb95a767fda9366d63b661d7d39e077d5118e4/src/pyinputplus/__init__.py#L172)

Perhaps

```py
while True:
    value = input("Please enter a number (q to quit): ")
    if value.startswith(('Q', 'q')):
        sys.exit("quit")
    try:
        value = int(value)
    except ValueError as ex:  # custom error message below!
        print("invalid input '{}', expected int".format(value))
    else:  # did not raise Exception
        break  # escape while loop
```

---

If you're ever looking for what a specific Exception is, `repr()` is very useful

```py
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError("some string")
... except IOError:
...     print("reached IOError")
... except Exception as ex:
...     print("unexpected Exception: {}".format(repr(ex)))
...     raise ex
...
unexpected Exception: ValueError('some string')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: some string
```